# Renamed: Solution for boilerplate code in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

*EDIT: This question turned out to have an interface solution that is not related to programming per se. The question is therefore not really regarding the r-language any more.*

*Original titel:* Paste code to R console, preserving line breaks and indention without formatting?

I'm looking for a way to easily store and subsequently print code to the R console. Preferably without having to deal with escaped special characters such as `\"`.

the `expr()` function is almost the right thing as it does not demand any formatting. Unfortunately it does not preserve line breaks:

```
# A)   
expr("17" %>%
       as.numeric())
```

is therefore equivalent of

```
# B) 
expr("17" %>% as.numeric())
```

Both printing:

```
"17" %>% as.numeric()
```

However, the functions I have found that do respect new lines and keeps indention demands escape characters. For example `glue()` from the glue package:

```
glue("
\"17\" %>%
  as.numeric()")
```

which prints beautifully:

```
"17" %>%
  as.numeric()
```

Is there any function already that can handle my problem?

I believe that my case is pretty much what the `"Error: unexpected ..."` output does in R when you for example have an extra `)` in the end of a call. But I do not know how to find the underlying code that produces those error messages.

Comment: For what purpose, exactly? Why do you need to print code to the R console? Are you aware of integrated exploratory programming environments such as ESS, Nvim-R and RStudio?

Comment: The purpose is to store chunks of code that are then easily accessible for copying from the console and pasting into code. 

I have been using Rstudio for 10 years, but have no experience of the other two you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe some implementation of `readClipboard()` is possible, paired with `eval()` ?

Comment: Why you want " copying from the console and pasting into code". It is a manual job. There may be a better way to do that automatically. Develop an example of the complete process and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @MarcosPérez, the idea is not to implement it as a part of a automatic workflow, but as kind of a customisable cheat-sheet for general code-snippets that I use fairly often, but have a tendency to forget. I already do this manually by using glue(), but I would like to streamline the process. So the basic functionality described above would do the job for me.

Comment: I’m still not clear what the actual *purpose* of this is. From the description in your comment it now sounds like what really want is the RStudio snippets feature. Is that it? Either way, pasting it into the console is *probably* the wrong way to go about it, and if you provide more details about your desired usage we might be able to provide more concrete advice.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, apparently it was clear enough for you to recommend a great solution. Rstudio snippets seems to be exactly the functionality I am looking for, although I did not know about it. Thanks! If you provide it as an answer I will flag it as accepted.

Now I don't really know if I should rephrase this question as some kind of Q&A or remove it completely as the solution is not really related to the R-language any more.

Comment: @Smerla Oh, cool! I agree that in this case your description was sufficient, I just assumed you meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many IDEs, including RStudio, have a feature to insert frequently-used [code snippets](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets) with placeholders.

These snippets can be added/customised in the preferences, and are accessible via the auto-completion menu.